# Remove id from link in rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have "cart/:id" link to "cart", this works ok when typing in the url 'store/cart'
but when I use a link it always includes the id

```
= link_to 'view cart', cart_path(@cart)
```

results in the url 'store/cart/1'

my routes.rb

```
 scope 'store' do
     resources :carts, only: [:destroy]
     match 'cart', to: 'carts#show', via: :get
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `resource` method.

Try this way:

```
scope 'store' do
  resource :cart, only: [:show, :destroy]
end
```

Here's [API docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

**UPDATE**

Also, avoid passing `@cart` to `cart_path`. Controller should figure out how to get resource instance without id in url.

Common way to get singular resource instance is to store database id in session or if you have some user authentication framework - link it to current user (most frameworks will ultimately puts user id in session).

Comment: try to avoid passing @cart to cart_path

Comment: You will need some sort of identifier. Maybe use the session?

Comment: Yes, you shall be able to get it from session.

Comment: without passing @cart gives the error "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts"} missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: please post routes as they are now. I suspect that you're still using resources not resource

Comment: exactly as you posted gives the error "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts", :format=>#<Cart id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-05 13:00:24", updated_at: "2013-09-05 13:00:24">} missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: you still passing @cart to cart_path?

Comment: also, do your controller named CartsController or CartController?

Comment: well, have you restart server after amending routes? not sure this is valid though, but worth a try

Comment: it's hard to track down this issue without current state of routes.rb, carts_controller.rb and view code that you is used to access CartsController#show action. Also, when last error raise: when accessing /cart url or when trying to generate link?